# Angular HTTP Interceptor how to chain an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, adal, adal.js

I am using the Azure AD adal library to do authentication. There is a call to aquire a token that returns an observable. How can this observable be added into the intercept? In the below example, how can I get the request that is set inside the subscribe to be returned as the Observable?

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.authAzureService.getAccessToken()
    .subscribe(token => {
      // I need this to be returned
      request = this.getRequestWithHeaders(request, token);
    });

    // This returns the request before the access token is added
    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Commecial Suicide I found the solution, which is to use a flatMap. Here is the code that worked:

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let requestHandler = this.authAzureService.getAccessToken()
    .flatMap(token => {
      request = this.getRequestWithHeaders(request, token);
      return next.handle(request);
    });
    return requestHandler;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you need to return something from `Observable`, you can use `map` instead of `subscribe`:

```
return this.authAzureService.getAccessToken()
  .map(token => request = this.getRequestWithHeaders(request, token));
}
```

Comment: I think this is close, but it's not quite right. When I do this, the "Get" never goes out across the wire.

Comment: Using a flatMap provided the solution. I'll post my code.

Answer (score -1):

```
request = request.clone({
  setHeaders: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
  }
});
return next.handle(request);
```